# Architecture Question - One Central Database and Many Different Programs Accessing It

Tags: c#, sql, linq, architecture

I am designing a program that will build and maintain a database, and act as a central server.  This is the 'first stage' of a grander plan.  Coming later will be 3-5 remote programs built around the information put into this database.

The requirements are:

1. The remote programs must be able to access the information in the database.
2. The remote programs must be able to set alerts when information in the database changes.
3. The remote programs must be able to request the central server to go out and fetch new / different data.

So, the question is this: how do I expose this data and events to the outside world?  My two choices are:

1. Have them communicate directly with my 'server' application.  This seems easier to:

   - do event notifications (although I suppose I'm probably missing something in SQL).
   - It also seems like this is more 'upgradeable' - that is I don't need to worry about the database updating and crashing all my remote programs because something changed.  I can account for this and transform it the data to a version the child program will understand.
2. Just go ahead and let them connect directly to the database.

   - This nice thing about this is that it's *solved*.  I can use LINQ for SQL.  The only thing the main server application needs to do is let the remote programs know where the database is.
   - I'm unsure how to trigger / relay 'events' for field changes in a database over different programs that may or may not be on the same computer.

Forgive my ignorance on this question.  I feel woefully unprepared to ask it, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to get started with this.  It is my first real DB project :-/

Thanks!

Comment: For #2, I assume you meant "... must be able to **get** alerts ..."?

Comment: I actually think I meant *trigger* alerts?  But I think they all get the same point across.  I've edited for clarity.  Thx.

Comment: It seems pretty split, but I've chosen writing an interface server-side.  My main worry is reverse compatibility: if I change the database a significant amount, a SOAP call from a very old app can still work.  Also, since there are alerts, there is going to need to be some sort of interface between the client apps and the non-database portion of the server.  It would be awkward to head to the server sometimes, and to the database others.  It'd be great to 'hide' all that behind a common interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the other programs are going to need to know about updates to the database, then the best solution is to manage all db updates through your server application so it can alert clients of the changes.  Otherwise it will be tough for the clients to be aware of changes to the db.  This also has the advantage of hiding the implementation details of your storage solution from the clients, so you are free to change databases, etc...

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to go with option 1. Build out a web service that can provide the information they all need. This will be the most flexible and allow you to reduce duplicate backend code that would happen with direct communication with the database.

Comment: Code duplication is something I actually hadn't considered.  Many of the interactions with the database would be the exact same.

Comment: Well, the backend code would only be "duplicated" for option #2 in the sense that multiple clients would be running it whereas the same code would only be run by a single web service in option #1. In terms of programming effort/lines of code etc., they're more or less the same.

Comment: @MusiGenesis You are correct, as re-reading my answer it was not as clear. I was also referring to where it also gets deployed. If you share the same code but have it deployed on several servers, or who knows how many desktops, it is a lot more work to push out changes to everyone when they occur.

Comment: yeah, but auto-updating clients is pretty easy to do in .NET, and it's something the OP will presumably have to implement anyway, regardless of whether he goes with option #1 or option #2.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at some Data Source design patterns first. This types of patterns will help you come up with solutions about how to manage the states of your data. Otherwise I think that I would require some more information about your requirements for the clients to make any further useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you learn about SQL Server and/or databases first. You don't appear to realize that most of what you want from your "central server" can all be done by SQL Server itself.

Comment: I don't, I know :-/  It's been years so I feel like I'm starting from scratch.  Hence I'm here!  I'll go read up on SQL Server.  Any good suggestions on where to start?

Comment: @user: "here" is a good place for specific questions. But you are asking something much broader. Start on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver/default.

Comment: +1 with the caveat that one advantage of the webservice mediator approach is that you can relatively easily swap database vendors. Personally, I've never actually seen this happen in 15 years, so it's probably a dubious advantage at best.

Answer (score 1):

A central databse is the simplest option and the cheapest to both build and maintain.

There are however a few scenarios where a central database could cause problems:

- High load on one of the systems: A high load on one of the systems could reduce performance on the other systems. For example someone running an internal report stops you being able to take orders on your eCommerce site.
- With several systems writing to the same database there is a greater chance of locking.
- With several systems dependent on the same database schema, how do you upgrade? All systems at the same time?
- If you need to take down the database all systems stop.